# Get values from a row based on some rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve how to handle a SQL query that will aggregate some data together.  Here is my sample data set.

```
SITE     STATUS     VENDOR          
1234     Rejected   Joe
1234     Rejected   John
1234     Approved   Jane
1234     Rejected   Jeb
5644     Rejected   Joe
5644     Rejected   John
5644     In Process Jane
8877     Rejected   Joe
8877     Rejected   John
```

I would like the resulting data set to look like the following

```
1234    Approved   Jane
5644    In Process Jane
8877    Rejected
```

There can be anywhere between 1 and 10 records for the same site.  There is a hierarchy for the status.  For example if any of the statuses on a site are Approved then all of the others do not matter.

I do realize this is a similar question as some other questions that have been asked before.  This is my first post.  If you find another post that seems to match what I am looking for feel free to share it.

Here is an example of the query that I had written:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SITE]

  ,(SELECT

        CASE 
            WHEN MIN(Status) = 'Completed' THEN 'Completed'
            WHEN MIN(Status) = 'In Process' THEN 'Shopping'
            WHEN MIN(Status) = 'Rejected' THEN 'Rejected'
            WHEN MIN(Status) = 'Withdrawn' THEN 'Withdrawn'
            WHEN MIN(Status) = 'Hold' THEN 'Hold'
             ELSE 'No Status' 
        END AS status

    FROM [dbo].[test] subtest
    WHERE test.SITE = subtest.SITE AND subtest.OverallStatus = 'A' GROUP BY site) AS test_status

    ,Vendor

FROM [dbo].[test] test
WHERE OverallStatus = 'A'
ORDER BY SITE
```

Sorry was editing my code from my environment and might have missed some changes.  OverallStatus is a value in the table just not shown.

Comment: looking at this... a case statement to define the order of status then you can sort by

Comment: is this mssql 2008r2 or later?

Comment: please find solution in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5720

Comment: Your sample code doesn't work against the table you've provided. What are `OverallStatus` and `ring`?

Comment: hey @KirkBroadhurst, i made the solution before it was updated... who knew!

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit strange that there is no vendor on `rejected`.  But, one way to do prioritization is using `row_number()` with a fancy `order by`:

```
select site, status,
       (case when status <> 'Rejected' then vendor end) as vendor
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by site
                                order by (case when status = 'Approved' then 1
                                               when status = 'In Process then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Having no vendor for rejected is on purpose.   But the more I look at my original ask I may have asked it a little off.  I am going to go back to the drawing board and look at the code you supplied.  Thanks!  I will try and post back

Answer (score 0):

if you provide your hierarchy of statuses, i can try writing query.

The idea is:
You can provide some numbering for your status (kind of prioritizing) in the order of your hierarchy in new table and you can join with this table and select site with highest/lowest (depends on your numbering)  status number.

Comment: The following would be the order I would go for.   Completed -1  In Process - 2   Rejected - 3.    An so on, with a template I could modify.  Thanks for giving it a try